# Loading a sentinel-2 image for a specific date and over a specified area of interest (given as coordinates)

Tags: google-earth-engine

I want to load a sentinel 2 scene for a specific date (24 June 2018) over a specific area of interest given by these coordinates 1: [130.887,-12.669] 2: [130.887,-12.927] 3: [131.156,-12.927] 4: [131.156,-12.669].

How do I go about this?

Code I m using is

```js
// Load sent 2 data, filter by date and bounds. 
var collection = ee.ImageCollection('sent2') 
.filterDate('2018-04-25', '2018-06-5') 
.filterBounds(ee.Geometry.Point((130.887, -12.669), (130.887, -12.927), (131.156, -12.927), (131.156, -12.669))
```

Comment: Hi Mary, here is the answer: https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/ic_filtering

Comment: Hi Rodrigo - I m still not quite sure it doesn't show me any image - I need an image for June 24 2018 from sentinel-2 within the following location (coordinates) 1: [130.887,-12.669] 2: [130.887,-12.927] 3: [131.156,-12.927] 4: [131.156,-12.669]- would be super appreciative if you could show me in a code how to write to find it . for some reason I receive nothing. Problem with the filer date command is that if filters out a specific date range

Comment: OK, update the question and post the code you've tried and why it isn't working, what you see and what you expect

Comment: // Load sent 2 data, filter by date and bounds.
var collection = ee.ImageCollection('sent2')
  .filterDate('2018-04-25', '2018-06-5')                                                                 
  .filterBounds(ee.Geometry.Point((130.887, -12.669), (130.887, -12.927), (131.156, -12.927), (131.156, -12.669));

Comment: It didn't like my code at all I think the last line specifying geometry has a cross alltogether

Comment: Put the code in the question

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to construct a point using many pairs of coordinates (lon, lat). Maybe you want a Polygon:

```
var polygon = ee.Geometry.Polygon([[130.887, -12.669], [130.887, -12.927],[131.156, -12.927], [131.156, -12.669]])
Map.addLayer(polygon)
Map.centerObject(polygon)

// Then, filter collection
// Load sent 2 data, filter by date and bounds. 
var collection = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2') 
                   .filterDate('2018-04-25', '2018-06-5') 
                   .filterBounds(polygon)
print(collection)
```

Comment: Awesome thanks soso much Rodrigo! this was the big problem for me I somehow couldn't get the polygon loaded but just pasted your code and it worked :) saved my day!